# play framework AskTimeoutException 2.1.5

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

My play framework application encounters this problem, it throws out AskTimeoutException exception. My logical is simple: an api which gets data from mysql. like

```
public List<string> getData(){
    //code to get data from mysql
}
```

any help is thanksful!

Comment: What is the question or issue? Not enough info to work.

Comment: @Inceptor361  it throws out the AskTimeoutException.